# How to convert a string to a stream object in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I want to make a string fit for consumption as a stream, by e.g. `Get-FileHash` command (using its `-InputStream` parameter).

The reason I want this is that I need to digest a string, and not contents of a file. I do not want to temporarily store said string in a file just to digest it.

I know this can be done with some half a dozen .NET objects, which is trivially supported by Powershell, but I am just curious whether there is an existing PS command or combination thereof that turns a string object into a stream, so I can do something like the following (assuming the hypothetical `Convert` turns the string into a stream)?

```
Get-FileHash -InputStream (Convert "Quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.") -Algorithm SHA512
```

Comment: `Get-FileHash -InputStream ([IO.MemoryStream]::new([Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("Quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."))) -Algorithm SHA512`

Comment: Please make it an answer, as it rightfully should be!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use some .NET functions:

```
$stream = [IO.MemoryStream]::new([Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("Quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."))
Get-FileHash -InputStream $stream -Algorithm SHA512
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a script in the Microsoft Script Gallery that does exactly what you ultimately want to do - that is, it takes a string and returns the hash for the string. See [Get-StringHash in the Technet Powershell Script Gallery](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-StringHash-aa843f71).