# Error: Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters

Tags: powershell

Trying to write a simple PowerShell script, but got stuck with an error, and I can't find any solution on the web.

```
$stream = [IO.MemoryStream]::new([Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes('aaaaaaaaaa!'))
Get-FileHash -InputStream $stream -Algorithm SHA512
AddPnPFile -Path './bundle.json' -Folder "$($FolderRelativeURLGeneral)$($folder)" -Stream $stream
```

Why am I getting an error for providing a stream to the Stream parameter? Removing the parameter solved the issue, but obviously I want to write something to the file, so can someone tell me how to write content to the file? Do I need to create a filestream out of the stream? However, the documentation doesn't specify that it has to be a file stream. How come it doesn't work?

[How to convert a string to a stream object in Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48322960/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-stream-object-in-powershell)

Comment: what is the _exact error_? PoSh errors usually have a good deal of useful info ... [*grin*] add it to your Question, not in the comments ... and please use code formatting so it will be easily readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PowerShell, a parameter set specifies which parameters can be used **together** when calling a function.

You can use parameters from one set **or** another set, you cannot mix and match.

Checking the documentation for [**`Add-PnPFile`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/add-pnpfile?view=sharepoint-ps), `Path` and `Folder` are part of one parameter set, while `Folder` and `Stream` are part of another; there is no parameter set that has all 3 parameters.

I think you're looking for `FileName` (which i assume creates a file from the stream) instead of `Path` (which is a local file path).